# Adyen web Drop-in v5.0.0 ++

Tags: adyen

in web Drop-in v 5.0.0 ++ i'cant use CreatePaymentReversalRequest ,
CreatePaymenCancelRequest , CreatePaymentRefundRequest.....
How to solve this problem knowing that I am using adyen-java-api-library version 17.1.0 on my spring boot app?? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Adyen Java API [v17.2.0](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-java-api-library/releases/tag/17.2.0) (or better to latest version [v17.4.0](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-java-api-library/releases/tag/17.4.0)) and you should see the necessary models (ie CreatePaymentReversalRequest, etc..) and logic.